# Security questions on Git

Tags: git, gitlab

Some developers of my company would like to use Git (and GitLab) instead of Subversion. We develop software for the financial sector, so the use of the version control system must be secure.

#### Question 1

You can manipulate `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` in order to pretend to be someone else (e.g. an ex-colleague). Can you prevent this or at least find out who did this?

#### Question 2

You can manipulate the date of your commit using the environment variables `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`. Can you prevent this or at least find out who did this?

Comment: If you want to be sure who made a commit you need to use [signed commits](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When moving from Subversion to git, it is important to bear in mind that a git commit doesn't precisely map to an svn commit. In git, there is a separate step of creating one or more commits, and *pushing* them to the server.

What you want to closely monitor are the *push* operations, because those actually change the state of the repository as observed by others. Also note that a single push may introduce many new commits, sometimes by different authors. As for security:

- In a typical git server, a push is authorized using an [SSH key](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key), so it should be as secure as SSH itself (i.e. very secure).
- Individual commits can further be [signed](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work).

Dates recorded in the commit are mostly irrelevant because again what matters is the time a set of commits is pushed to the server. Individual commit dates serve as more of a reminder to the author than as a serious tracking tool. You need to check with your git provider whether and how they track times of pushes received from users.

Comment: Thank you! I think we will choose a combination between trusting our devs and analysing who pushed what.